Next.js homepage redirecting to the previous page
I'm encountering a rare scenario with my Next.js application. Please check out the Loom link for a detailed explanation: Loom Video.
https://www.loom.com/share/80303d6ac1a3407f954f6d549421932b
I've tried different methods to resolve the issue. The home page works fine after restarting the server but turns black after a few minutes. Has anyone faced this scenario before? Any advice would be greatly appreciated.
Homepage.jsx
https://codeshare.io/nAXZNj

is there a middleware.ts file in you project. if yes can you edit the question with this

and your page.tsx (Home page) code

No middleware public route, Thank you

edit the question with your homepage code

Edited, Thank you

Please provide a minimal reproducible example (preferably without requiring external links) https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
